# Scala and Spring - tricky case?

Tags: spring, scala

I want to instantiate a bean with Spring using a `factory-method`.
However, the trick is that I want to access the current `ApplicationContext` in my factory method.

Here's the code I tried:

```
object ActorSystemFactory {

  var applicationContext: ApplicationContext = _

  def createActorSystem = {
    val system = ActorSystem("AkkaScalaSpring")
    SpringExtensionImpl(system)(applicationContext) //need applicationContext here
    system
  }
}

class ActorSystemFactory extends ApplicationContextAware {

  //Spring warns that createActorSystem does not exist here!! and it is...right
  //Indeed, it is present in the companion object to make it "static" equivalent.    

  def setApplicationContext(applicationContext: ApplicationContext) {
    ActorSystemFactory.applicationContext = applicationContext
  }

}
```

My declaration in xml:

```
<bean id="actorSystem" class="com.myPackage.ActorSystemFactory" factory-method="createActorSystem">
</bean>
```

Regarding the comment in the `ActorSystemFactory` class, how to handle the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I managed to do the trick.

In fact, now I don't use the static factory-method technique but rather the instance factory-method technique:

```
class ActorSystemFactory extends ApplicationContextAware {

  def createActorSystem = {
    val system = ActorSystem("AkkaScalaSpring")
    SpringExtensionImpl(system)
    system
  }

  def setApplicationContext(applicationContext: ApplicationContext) {
    ActorSystemFactory.applicationContext = applicationContext
  }
}

object ActorSystemFactory {

  var applicationContext: ApplicationContext = _

}



<bean id="actorSystemFactory" class="myPackage.ActorSystemFactory"/>

<bean id="actorSystem" factory-bean="actorSystemFactory" factory-method="createActorSystem" />
```

(http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html) (no matter the version of Spring is)

The whole works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

spring bean by default is singleton. you can have your actor system instantiated directly in the class, no need for an object

Comment: If I do that, the `createActorSystem` method would not be "static".